# Possible to do well in Algebra without loving Analysis much?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, soft-question

Having taken some courses in higher algebra, I realized that what I truly appreciate in mathematics is abstract algebra. But it also appears that I'm not a big fan of real analysis [at least I don't seem to have a good feel of topology, and I don't seem to enjoy some other things in analysis either, and I'm not even half-way though the real analysis course yet]. I'm wondering though, how is it possible that I can do well in algebra, and feel so lost in topology (and maybe other parts of real analysis)? And I don't even have real interest in those topics in real analysis, not also mentioning that I just want to focus on algebra. I'm surprised by this, but this is what life is showing me.

So, what do you, dear math people, think, can a person generally do well in advanced algebra, without having much love for, and without being very good in analysis?

Comment: Despite hating every algebra class I've ever taken, it's really the only thing that I'm good at. I have never been able to grasp real analysis very well. I wouldn't worry that you're all alone in that boat.

Definitely it helps to be decent in real analysis so that you may make extra connections or analogies between the two subjects, but they're mostly two independent subjects at the lower levels.

Comment: That is perfectly possible, within certain limits. However, if you want to go into research, you should aim to be comfortable with all the topology and analysis that are typically mandatory at the graduate level. The content of Knapp's *Basic Real Analysis* and *Advanced Real Analysis* is a reasonable amount of real analysis for an algebraist. Also learn some other topics such as complex analysis, differential geometry and algebraic topology. Have a look here: http://www.math.harvard.edu/quals/index.html

Comment: If you love algebra and hate topology, what will you do later in your studies when subjects like algebraic topology come up? ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, either I won't be interested in it on a deep level as to pursue it seriously, or I will like it, since it's algebraic :)

Comment: I used to feel the same way as you (and still often do). I find myself to be strong in algebraic subjects, but weaker in analytical subjects. I've found, however, that if you're strong in algebra, it might be best to make your way to topology first. Then analysis will become clearer - you'll have a better geometric feel. You'll eventually find that time is progress, and progress is time.

Comment: @boldbrandywine: it is probably not easy to study topology without studying some real analysis first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some extent I think so. You don't have to love every sub-discipline in order to excel in some.

However I don't think you should assume that you will suck on analysis for that reason. First of all you're probably required to take the Real analysis course and also some multi-dimensional analysis. Second there are parts of analysis that are very algebra-like, for example functional analysis can be viewed as a special kind of linear algebra. Also topology has aspects that could be appealing to the algebra-minded person I think.

Bottom line is that if you're going to do advanced algebra you will have to do some basic analysis just as you must do some basic algebra to do advanced analysis.

Also bear in mind and be open to the fact that things can change. When you're ready for advanced mathematics you may have changed your mind...

Comment: In linear algebra you usually work with finite dimensional vectorspaces, don't you? At least I wouldn't call functional analysis a special kind of linear algebra. It's more like the generalisation to infinite dimensional vectorspaces.

Comment: What do you consider advanced mathematics? @skyking

Comment: @menag You're so limited minded;) The concept of linear algebra doesn't restrict to finite-dimensional vector spaces, the concept of linear algebra is larger than that and even those cases introduced in functional analysis is just sub set of what linear algebra covers.

Comment: @sequence It's a bit of a floating definition (where the distinction between basic and advanced is). I'd definitely would say that real analysis is to be considered basic at least. The courses that your school basically "forces" you to take is basic, while those that are not mandatory, yet requires you to have taken the basic courses could be considered advanced.

Comment: @skyking, my school has three versions of real analysis - one is what is called "applied real analysis", the next one is "introduction to real analysis", and, finally, "real analysis", which is very, very hard, even for many of those students who have done well in other courses. So the applied real analysis course is mandatory for many programs in applied math, or for a joint in pure math. For pure math majors, the hardest one is mandatory. The one I'm taking now is in-between, a preparatory course for the hardest real analysis one.